# C# IS operator cannot be used in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

In the following code, the compiler apparently cannot determine the right type for "t".

```
_supportedElements.Any(t => element is t)
```

Hovering the mouse above the second t does not mention the type as usual. The compiler gives an error that there is no type or namespace t.

_supportedElements is defined as:

```
private Type[] _supportedElements = { typeof(TextField), typeof(CheckBox), typeof(RadioButton), typeof(SelectList), typeof(TableRow), typeof(Link), typeof(Button) };
```

When I change this to:

```
_supportedElements.Any(t => elementGetType() == t)
```

there is no compiler error and also hovering the mouse above the second t correctly states the type. But I really need to use the IS operator.

Is this a quirk in Visual Studio 2013 SP4 or in myself...?

---

Edit:

After all your responses it is clear now the quirk is in me...
My intention was to create an array with types to validate the current type against. That was not possible and I did not realize that I created an array of instances when I surrounded the classnames with "typeof".
The error message was misinterpreted by me as "You did not declare t, I don't know it" instead of "you must use a Type after "is", not a type instance".

I really appreciate the quick response with examples and alternatives. Hopefully I will be as helpful to others at the Stackoverflow site :-)

Comment: Why do you need to use the `is` operator?

Comment: And since _supportedElements  is an array of Types then, well the is operator seems unlikely to be what you want, ie they will all be x is System.Type and not a lot else

Comment: Taking a stab in the dark perhaps you want t => t.IsAssignableFrom(element) ???

Comment: `is` requires the Type name, not the Type object so, no, that won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is this a quirk in Visual Studio 2013 SP4 or in myself...?**

Its you. The compiler is telling you the problem. You're not following the syntax, which is

```
someInstance is ClassName
```

you cannot do this:

```
someInstance is typeof(ClassName)
```

you can do this:

```
someInstance.GetType() == typeof(ClassName)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are checking if one instance `is` another instance, not a type.

Comment: @EagleBeak, and so? `t` is an instance of type `System.Type` not a type itself.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry. I misread your answer and thought you referred to the "is" keyword itself, not his code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = new MyType();

Type[] _supportedElements = { typeof(MyType), typeof(int), typeof(string)};

// True
var isAcceptedType = _supportedElements.Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(element.GetType()));

var notSupportedElement = 'a';

// False
isAcceptedType =  _supportedElements.Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(notSupportedElement.GetType()));
```